# PHP trim/rtrim/ltrim VS Regular expression

Tags: php, regex, trim

I tend to use `rtrim`, `ltrim` and `trim` to strip off spaces at the end, left or right. I also use them to strip off the characters at the end or the beginning of the string. Is it faster than a regular expression? Is there anything wrong with the following code?

```
 $string = " hello: ";
 $string = rtrim(trim($string), ":"); //hello
```

Would it make any difference if I were to use a regular expression in terms of performance?

Comment: Why not `trim($string, ': ')`? Could a colon ever be in front of `' hello:'`?

Comment: no and there is no guaranteed space afterwards either. Thats why I use both trim and rtrim

Comment: I would say `trim|ltrim|rtrim` would be faster then `regex`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regular expressions usually make things slower, especially applied to such small strings, due to the expression analysis overhead.

Assuming that a colon would never appear on the left side, you could eliminate the `rtrim()`:

```
$string = trim($string, ": "); // trim either space or colon on either side
```

Comment: does this work if there is no space but only colon on the right side ?

Comment: If you're only processing small strings and are not doing any other string validation, then the trim functions are the way to go, however if you're going to do some validation with regex anyway, then it might be easier to simply exclude the leading and trailing whitespace within your regex.